# Timeout images when server down to prevent cluster overload?

Tags: php, load-balancing, high-availability, haproxy

This is a somewhat complex situation. We serve our application off of 16 load balanced servers that sit behind haproxy. We serve the images associated with the app from another server running nginx that also sits behind a haproxy load balancer. We have a global CDN that pulls images from this image server and caches them for future serving, so the load on this server is very low even though we handle 300 million or so images.

Now, yesterday we had to swap a drive in the raid array for the image server. When we took it down, we of course expected some of our images to no longer load, but instead we ran into a far more serious issue. The connections to the app servers skyrocketed and nothing in our cluster was able to be served. My thought is that the app requests came into the load balancer, hit an app server and hung there while waiting for images to be served. Since the server was down, the requests continued to come in, and the whole system was locked up.

I would obviously like to avoid this situation in the future. Any suggestions for where we likely need to look to set a sane timout for this, or how to handle it at the load balancer? I would prefer that our app loads as usual, just without images if this happens.

Comment: I would suggest tell your designers to use HTML5.Canvas instead of images. ;)

Comment: But, usually the client browser, would access the image server. not your 16 web server grid. Am I wrong?

Comment: why did you tag this php?

Comment: If the app is designed to wait for an images that is not available then that is design problem with the app.  The app should check for the image and if it is not available return a "file not available" response.  And why did you take down the image server to swap a drive in the raid array - most raid will swap hot.

Comment: HTML Canvas isn't an option. I should clarify a bit. The images are being served via our api which returns a json response with the data to our clients. We also do ad serving which pulls back both images and the json data from our api to create a display ad on a client web site.

Comment: blam: It is a hot swap drive, but in this case the datacenter tech took the server down. They didn't need to, but i'm glad they did because it exposed this problem.

Comment: Found the issue, but haven't found a solution yet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14420093/nfs-mount-soft-mount-timeout-too-slow

Answer (score 1):

You should look at --

```
    timeout server 50000
    timeout client 50000
```

It's generally a bad idea to set these low, because it's only once the "timeout connect" has established. However, lowering them will adjust the timeout value for an established connection.

You could also tune

```
    timeout http-request
```

That will adjust the maximum time to wait for an HTTP request.